# Gcloud ML Engine adds extra dimension to input array

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

Trying to set up the Gcloud ML Engine with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, 3], name='x')
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 2]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w), name='y')

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)
tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y)

prediction_signature = (
    tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs={'inputs': tensor_info_x},
        outputs={'scores': tensor_info_y},
        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)
    )

export_path = './test_exports'
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
           'predict_images':
               prediction_signature
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
builder.save()
```

A sample input JSON file I used for prediction is:

```json
{ "inputs" : [[ 0.32439028, 0.07830289, 0.30881251], [ 0.32439028, 0.07830289, 0.30881251]] }
```

As you can see, the shape of the input array is (2, 3). However, when feeding this as input to the model, I'm facing an error:

> Cannot feed value of shape (1, 2, 3) for Tensor u'x:0', which has
>   shape '(?, 3)' (Error code: 2)

To test this further, on giving an input of size (1, 3), the model works perfectly. Any idea how the extra dimension is getting added?

EDIT :

Command used to test:

```bash
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=./test_exports --json-instances inputs.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution for anyone working on the same.

Taking the example shown in the question, the inputs given by the ml engine to the model are in the shape [1, N, m] where N is the number of inputs and m is the feature size. So to convert the inputs to this format, use `tf.squeeze()` as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[1, None, 3], name='x')
x_exp = tf.squeeze(x, axis=0)
```

Now you can use `x_exp` for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

ML Engine predicts for a batch of inputs, not just one.  So you should change your serving input placeholder to [ None, 2, 3 ]

Incidentally, having your model process a batch would be better for training as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm a bit confused. My inputs are supposed to be single dimensional arrays of length 3. So, to make it as batch, I gave the size of x as [None,3]. The process does a matrix multiplication of [N,3] input and [3,w] weight matrices, where N represents the number of inputs in batch. I cannot change X's shape to [None,2,3] since the size 2 isn't fixed. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Aah.  In your json file, put different instances on different lines. Your inputs needs to be a 1d array.

Comment: It got solved by doing `tf.squeeze()` to the input variable.